# select2 ajax not firing on space input

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 (v4.0.12) with Ajax (remote data) in asp.net core mvc web app. Remote data returns clients (name + surname) and they all contain a space between name and surname.

**Everything works great** **except** when a user inputs an empty space. Then the search event is not firing and there is a JS error in the browser `Uncaught TypeError: i._removeOldTags is not a function`.

I tried setting the tags and multiple to false, but it doesn't help. Is there a setting I'm missing?

The setup is pretty basic:

html select control:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="ddlClients">
    <option value="0">... select client ...</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```js
$("#ddlClients").select2({
    tags: false,
    multiple: false,
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    minimumResultsForSearch: 10,
    language: {
        inputTooShort: function () {
        return 'Enter min 2 chars...';
    }
},
ajax: {
    url: '/MyController/GetClientsData',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    data: function (params) {
    var queryParameters = {
        term: params.term
        }
        return queryParameters;
        },
    processResults: function (data) {
        return {
        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
        return {
        text: item.text,
        id: item.id
        }
    })
    };
    }
    }
});
```

c# (controller)

```cs
public IActionResult GetClientsData(string term)
{
var result = GetDataFromMyDb(term)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        id = x.Value,
        text = x.Text,
    })
    .ToList();

    return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: Are there any other codes related? the codes you've shown works well in my case,and I couldn't reproduce your error

Comment: It's a really big project so there is a lot of other code. I'll make a test in a new (empty) project and get back to you.

Comment: Apparently something is wrong in my project, because the code works for me also in a new (empty) project. Thank you